# Laravel determine when field was updated

Tags: php, laravel

I want to diplay when my status field was updated how is it possible? Timestamps are not solution in this situation.
my model

[image]

Comment: If you do not keep a field like `updated_at`, there is no way of telling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot determine when a specific model attribute has been last updated without some tracking of the attribute changes.

If timestamps are not an option, I'd highly suggest you to opt for an audit log system that has a database composed like this:

`id | entity_id | entity_type | attribute | old_value | new_value | created_at`

Everytime an attribute changes, you create a new entry in the database, logging the old and the new value.

You can also add a new column to specify who has made a particular change!

Comment: I think that this is a best solution in this situation